# How to take periodic snapshots while running a simulation in VASP?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, conceptual-dft, aimd

Same question, rephrased:

What is the procedure to take snapshots at fixed intervals while running an AIMD or DFT Simulation in VASP?

OR

Which parameter in the INCAR file do I modify to achieve periodic snapshots(in JPG/PNG) of atomic positions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no way to do this directly in VASP, but you can achieve this goal using the [Atomic Simulation Environment](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/) (ASE). With your `OUTCAR` available, do the following:

```py
from ase.io import read, write
images = read('OUTCAR',index=':') # Read in every iteration
interval = 5 # Save .png every N steps
for i, image in enumerate(images):
     if i+1 % interval == 0:
          write('image_'+str(i)+'.png',image) # Write out imamge
```

Answer (score 7):

In can be done easily using python or bash script. You have to keep looking for changes in `OSZICAR`. Whenever OSZICAR prints 'F' i.e. end of electronic self consistent loop, copy your `CONTCAR` to other file. There is simple tool in linux system `inotify-hookable` which will watch over change in `CONTCAR` file.

```
    inotify-hookable -f CONTCAR -c "cp CONTCAR CONTCAR.new"
    echo "== $(date) : executed, continuing to monitor..."
```

use `sudo apt-get install inotify-hookable` to install in ubuntu or use source code.